# Javascript push to local storage array not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On an onclick event in React (don't think React's causing the problem, I think it's how I'm handling the object & array), I'm trying to grab a local storage variable and push an element (key) to it, however it's throwing the error **'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of null.'**

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Images from './images';

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        // If doesn't exist, create empty instance
        let selectedImages = localStorage.getItem('selectedImages') ? localStorage.getItem('selectedImages') : { ids : [] };

        return selectedImages;
    },
    selectImage(key) {
        // get localstorage
        let selectedImages = localStorage.getItem('selectedImages');

        // Create instance of ids array and push key
        let selectedImagesArray = selectedImages.ids.push(key);
        // set .ids as selectedImagesArray
        selectedImages.ids = selectedImagesArray;   

        // Set new local storage
        localStorage.setItem('selectedImages', selectedImages);

    },
    render() {
        let selectedImages = localStorage.getItem('selectedImages');
        return (
            <Images items={feedData.items} 
                    selected={selectedImages} 
                    selectImage={this.selectImage} />
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like `localStorage.getItem('selectedImages');` is returning `null` so of course `ids` can't be accessed from `null`. Also, you know that `push` returns the array length right? not the actual array.

Comment: `localStorage` can only hold strings .. you have to JSON serialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your app has following flow (considering empty localStorage):

1. **getInitialState:** returns `{ ids : [] }` but sets nothing to localStorage
2. **render**: render your component. On click goes to next step
3. **selectImage:**`let selectedImages = localStorage.getItem('selectedImages');` Pay attention that `selectedImages` is `null` cause you haven't set to localStorage anything yet
4. **selectImage:** `let selectedImagesArray = selectedImages.ids.push(key);` throws your error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of null."

And pay attention to @Matt's comment. Setting object to localStorage means settings string `"[object Object]"`, you have to serialize your data  before you set it ([JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)) and deserialize after your get it ([JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)).